# Парадокс печати в консоль

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<std::string> get_playlist(int day) {

std::vector<std::string> playlist;

ifstream playlist_file(get_path(day));

while (!playlist_file.eof())
{

    std::string str;

    std::getline(playlist_file, str);

    std::vector<std::string> temp = split(str, '.');
    std::string exe = temp[temp.size()-1];

    std::cout << exe << " <|> " << str << " <| " << std::endl;

    if (exe == std::string("mp4") || exe == std::string("avi")) {

        int vector_size = playlist.size();

        if (vector_size > 0) {
            bool is = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {
                if (playlist[i] == str) {
                    is = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (!is) {
                playlist.push_back(str);
                std::cout << str << std::endl;
            }

        } else {
            playlist.push_back(str);
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

return playlist;
}
```

Для отладки пытаюсь распечатать то что видит программа
std::cout << exe << " <|> " << str << " <| " << std::endl;

Но выхлоп неожиданный:
... 
 <|  Jay Sean - Maybe.mp3
 <|  Inferno Show - Iscariota.mp3
 <|  Dannii Minogue - You Won't Forget About Me.mp3
 <|  Antonio Carlos Jobim - A Felicidade.mp3
 <|  Nelly Furtado - Say It Right.mp3
 <|  Louie Vega & Julie McKnight - Diamond life.mp3
 <|  Adam Lambert - If I Had You.mp3
 <|  Passenger - Let Her Go.mp3
 <|  Noisettes - Never Forget You.mp3
mp3 <|> Morcheeba - Crimson.mp3 <|

Только последняя строка вывелась так как просили, почему?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что в строке есть непечатаемые символы. Попробуйте выводить так:

    std::cout << "EXE: [" << exe << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STR: [" << str << "]" << std::endl;

Comment: ===============>  
]XE: [mp3  
]TR: [Passenger - Let Her Go.mp3  
<===============  
===============>  
]XE: [mp3  
]TR: [Noisettes - Never Forget You.mp3  
<===============  
===============>  
EXE: [mp3]  
STR: [Morcheeba - Crimson.mp3]  
<===============  
  
Ну уже получше,
а std::getline возвращает перевод каретки?

Comment: @hitman249: не уверен, проверьте. Может быть, `getline` съедает `\n`, но не предыдущий `\r`? Это бы объяснило результат.

Comment: Странно все это. У меня в винде (MinGW) нормально работает

    ifstream in(av[1] ? av[1] : "t.cpp");
    string str;
    
    while (getline(in, str)) {
      str[strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r\n")] = 0; // delete CRNL
      cout << '[' << str << "]\n";
    }

что с 

      str[strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r\n")] = 0;

что без. Но, винда + кресты -- непредсказуемо...

@hitman249, бросайте Вы это творение им. Б.Гейтса.

Comment: @avp: судя по предыдущим вопросам, у ТС gcc. Проблема тут в том, что системная библиотека считает концом строки. Под виндой она обязана считать таковым `\r\n` (и превращать его в чистый `\n` во входном потоке), а под линуксом — нет. В результате если файл с `\r\n` читается под линуксом, `\r` попадёт в строку.

Comment: Ну, тут надо реальные данные смотреть и у ТС надо спросить  в какой системе он работает.

Кстати, я в пред. комменте ошибся. Конечно, удалять CRNL из **string** в C++ надо как-то так:

     #include <string.h>
     ...
     str.resize(strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r\n"));

Comment: у меня rasbian (debian) + gcc 4.6.3   
в исходнике присутствует /r/n  
  
такая комбинация помогла    
  
        str.resize(strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r\n"));
        str.resize(strcspn(str.c_str(), "\n"));
        str.resize(strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r"));

Comment: @hitman249, неужели одного раза недостаточно? 

Вообще-то, я бы для Вашего случая все начало цикла написал так:

      string str;
      while (getline(playlist_file, str)) {
        str.resize(strcspn(str.c_str(), "\r"));
        int extpos = (int)str.size() - 4;
        if (extpos > 0) {
          const char *p = str.c_str() + extpos;
          if (strcmp(p, ".avi") == 0 || strcmp(p, ".mp4") == 0)
     continue;
        }
        ....
      }

Да и дальше ... (места мало)  Просто ищите в цикле
  
      bool is = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if ((*v)[i] == str) { ...

Comment: Более идиоматический путь для C++:

    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t")+1);

(`.c_str()` может делать лишнюю копию.)

Comment: Точно, `.erase()` больше подходит, чем `.resize()`. 

Хотя, может лучше просто написать все это за 5 минут на чистом Си и не путаться в 3-х соснах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте-ка просуммирую дискуссию в комментариях между [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), [[@hitman249](/users/5984/hitman249)](/users/5984/hitman249) и мной.

Строки, которые читаются из файла, скорее всего записаны в Windows-формате: строки оканчиваются на `"\r\n"`. (Возможно, это часть стандарта формата `.m3u` — я не нашёл спецификации по формату в интернете.) Программа читает файл построчно, но системная библиотека интерпретирует строки в Unix-стандарте: `\n` считается концом строки, таким образом, `\r` остаётся в строке.

Если считанная строка `"Jay Sean - Maybe.mp3\r"`, она выводится так: (`exe == "mp3\r"`, `str == "Jay Sean - Maybe.mp3\r"`):

```
std::cout << exe << " <|> " << str << " <| " << std::endl;
```

выводит

```
mp3            <- возврат каретки без перевода строки, дальше с начала строки
 <|> Jay Sean - Maybe.mp3  <- снова возврат каретки
_<|_           <- _ означает пробел
```

Результат:

```
 <|  Jay Sean - Maybe.mp3
```

В последней строке файла, очевидно, не было символов перевода строки, поэтому она вывелась как ожидалось.

Как с этим бороться? Например, можно удалить символы типа перевода строки при чтении строки:

```
str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t") + 1);
```

(этот код отбрасывает последовательные пробелы, различные варианты конца строки и символы табуляции в конце строки).

Дополнение: если вы хотите, чтобы ваш код был переносимым и вёл себя одинаково на всех системах, нужно отключить системно-зависимую интерпретацию символов перевода строки. Для этого открывайте поток так:

```
ifstream playlist_file(get_path(day), ios_base::binary);
```